# A Python Web Framework that makes it easy to connect and use a Legacy Oracle DB?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, sqlalchemy, web2py

I'm looking to get some advice on a web application framework (strong preference for Python, but Ruby is OK too) that I can learn to help me eventually solve a need we have in my organization.

I'd like to create a chart/graph app that can help us better analyze the large amounts of data we have in new ways to find trends etc without investing lots of time for each different scenario.

The first part of this is the app to create charts from our data. We already use tools like Crystal Reports, but what I'm looking to create is something with a bit more business intelligence and the ability to link data together in a one off/add-hoc way.

Here are some of the specifics I'm hoping to accomplish:

- User level control/permissions. Who can CRUD on what areas.
- Link with legacy Oracle db and do as much querying (read only) as possible from Oracle
- Create some aggregate statistics (Monthly, Daily, every 15 min) based on data from the      Oracle DB that is manipulated to provide a different type of statistic that is not available in the Oracle db.  These would probably be stored on a local db. A scheduled tasks is the kind of thing I am thinking, so the data locally would update autonomously at regular intervals.
- Use a graphing library like Google Chart Tools or Highcharts to link the data to the HTML. Nice looking charts that are not burdensome to generate (for me or the server) and provide controls to update/filter the chart results for example limit the time time slice with a slider or filter results via a dropdown.
- Must operate on a Windows Server.

I have looked at a few frameworks and each has things that I like, but as a newcomer to the web framework world I am not really sure that I am aware of the “gotchas” I might run into here has been my observations so far. Note some of these may not be factual, I tried to research these issues but connecting webapps to Oracle is kind of a fringe case that not a lot of people do, so information is not as prolific as say PostgreSQL or MySQL.

- **Web2Py** – This seems to be the friendliest for the new developer, which is appealing to me. In the span of a day or so I was able to get a basic site up and running and connecting it to some dummy data to output some basic Google Chart Tools. I started researching connecting to Oracle servers and found that while it seems to have fairly decent support for the type of “legacy” connections, it is necessary to define by hand each model from the legacy database. For me this would be problematic. A few hundred tables with 30-150 columns each means a lot of “hand coding” some really tedious stuff. Add on top of that the fact that tables are added/schemas change 2-3 times a year, and it would be a management nightmare. One thing I really liked about web2py was that it had a scheduler built in, so pulling the necessary data from oracle on a regular basis would be fairly simple.
- **Django** – Once I discovered what a PITA it was going to be to do all the modeling in Web2Py I immediately looked at Django to see what it had to offer. It has better support for the module creation, providing a tool to create a model based on a legacy database. The documentation even admits it isn't perfect, but it would probably get me 90% there with a bit hand tweaking it could be very helpful. Unfortunately it doesn't have any official, and only very basic support for Oracle.
- **Flask** – I looked at Flask because of a good experience I had with SQLAlchemy when it came to this stuff. I didn't spend as much time looking at Flask as I had spent looking at Web2Py or Django, but what I saw looked nice. After facing another search through webapp documentation I decided I should consult some expert advice, and came here to post. 
  As I mentioned I used SQLAlchemy and really liked the way I was able to fairly easily define a basic skeleton for my model and tell alchemy to load the data from Oracle I think I would still need to add relationships but if that is all I have to add I'm way ahead of the game.

I know some people swap out the Django ORM with SQLAlchemy, but I wonder if that is a constant uphill battle or if it is something worth seriously undertaking?

My preference and ability lean more towards the Python frameworks, but I have done some Ruby work and would not be opposed to a really great Ruby framework that could accomplish all of this.

Beyond that I welcome any requests for clarification as well as any comments. Like I said I am fairly new to web frameworks and actually really enjoy learning new things, but want to spend my time productively working towards a launch of this project, not getting deep into things only to find I should have chosen a different framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once I discovered what a PITA it was going to be to do all the modeling in Web2Py I immediately looked at Django to see what it had to offer. It has better support for the module creation, providing a tool to create a model based on a legacy database.

I assume you're talking about Django's [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs#auto-generate-the-models) tool. Note, web2py includes a [similar tool](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/scripts/extract_pgsql_models.py) -- it was created for use with PostgreSQL but should be usable with other databases with minor tweaks (i.e., change the database driver to Oracle). If you need any help, feel free to ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Comment: I did mean the inspectdb tool Django provides, I was not aware of the tool you linked for web2py, that is very interesting to me and I will definitely be looking into adapting it to my purposes. 

Thanks for the info, with the scheduling stuff included in web2py it is a very appealing option for me.

Answer (score 0):

The main concern is `connection to oracle db` and `rendering charts`. 
`DB`- The best bet is `SQLAlchemy` because it supports `oracle` much better than other ORM out there.

Incase you want pythonic libraries to `render charts` you can use`numpy` and `scipy` charts, there are python libraries which supports `google charts` api. If you are building one to interact with `google charts` should have a look at requests [requests](http://python-requests.org).

When it comes to web framework, if ORM is replaced by default one ,you are pretty much left out with `forms`, `wsgi` and extra components. In this case I will fallback to `flask` which supports `REST` anf `flask.sqlalchemy` written by `Armin` the creator of `Flask` and `werkzeug`.

You have `flask admin` extension too.

Comment: The oracle bit is definitely the hardest piece of the puzzle, and from what I've seen [link](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is the best at handling that, so far ideal framework for me is something easy like web2py using SQLAlchemy as a backend. 

I looked at the python charting tools and they mostly seem geared towards generating image charts for publication + some other huge function (science clacs, statistics) not just charting. 

I've started to look more info Flask, it is quite nice, but seems a bit more hands on then something like web2py, I'll have to look into it more though.